Monitoring start and stop processes
Im trying to monitor the start and stop of processes on a server with auditd, using the following rule
-w /usr/bin/ -p x -k T1569.002

However, when raising an event to generate the log and searching it with ausearch, the only log it finds is the addition of the rule.

If the process is already loaded into memory, /usr/bin is not referenced on startup. Not all executables come from /usr/bin. Nor is the filesystem referenced at all on process exit.

If you want to monitor process start/stop, you probably want to monitor the execve and exit system calls. Take a look at this article.

See https://sematext.com/blog/linux-monitoring-tools/ and https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.htm and do an intrrnet search on "Perfomance Accounting" Performance Monitoring". Be prepared to drink from the firehose of data if you track process statt/stop.
